# Usb Live No hardisk

Tags: live-usb

Ok so i own a Toshiba laptop , and the thing is  my hdd went bad,but i had a USB flash drive with  i live CD Ubuntu on it. Now i don't have and hdd plugged in my laptop I'm only with a flashdrive.

My question is how much memory does this live CD support cause my flash drive is 32 gigs and after about 1.5 gigs of downloads a screen shows up and tells me that i don't have enough space left.

The other thing is I don't have money to get a hdd right now so i wanna use this flash drive for now but can I somehow customize the CD through the live edition so i could have programs that i need after restarts I tried with Customization Live CD but when i run it , it stops and in my terminal it says **could not execute not enough space**.

So if anyone can tell me what can I do with this problem I'm having with space on my live USB Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the LiveUSB you get the option of setting the size of the persistence file.  It generally defaults to about 1GB.  You can increase the size of the persistence file with a bit of fiddling, however since the LiveUSB has to boot off a FAT32 partition the size of the persistence file will still be limited to 4Gb - The maximum file size under FAT32.

I suggest what you should do given your current situation, is to make a full install to the 16Gb pendrive.  This will boot quite a bit slower than the LiveCD, but has the advantage that it is a full install and can be updated and added to up to the limit of the 16Gb which will be available under ext4.

Find a smaller USB stick to put the LiveUSB on and use that to install Ubuntu to the 16Gb stick as a full install.  If you want speed and functionality at the expense of sophistication, you could try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) instead of Ubuntu.  This is much more lightweight and will boot faster and be a little more snappy than Ubuntu with Unity while running off a USB stick.

Be quite certain that you are installing grub2 to the 16GB stick.  A common problem when installing in this mode is that Ubiquity will default to the first device it finds to put the grub bootloader on.  If this happens to be the wrong device, then the 16GB stick will not have the bootloader installed and you will have to do some work to fix it.